# How to overload an iterator function without losing the advantages of the iterator

Tags: .net, vb.net, yield-return

Since I usually use VB.net as my language of choice I didn't cope with `yield`ing yet. Now I read, that they introduced `yield`ing to VB.net as well, so I tried to learn about it, and now I have a question.

Let's say I have an `Iterator` function that uses `yield`ing. For the sake of this question I created this rather useless function:

```
Public Iterator Function Test(ByVal gap As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Dim running As Integer

    Do While running < (Integer.MaxValue - gap)
        Yield running
        running += gap
    Loop
End Function
```

If I understood `yield`ing correctly, than the code stops after the `yield`ing and only continues, when the next item is asked for.

So, in my example... if getting the next value for the `running` variable would need 1 second, then my code would only run 1 second if I only need the first number and it would run 5 seconds if I'd need 5 numbers.

So far, so good, but now I want to overload my function:

```
Public Function Test() As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Return Test(1)
End Function
```

It's not an `Iterator` function anymore, so did I lose the advantage of only needing as much time as I need numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's not an Iterator function anymore, so did I lose the advantage of only needing as much time as I need numbers?

You did not. Iterator functions are not magic, all they do is give you a convenient way of implementing the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface. So, to get the advantage of producing only the values you require, all you need is a method that returns a good implementation of that interface. And that could be any of:

- An iterator method, like your `Test(ByVal gap As Integer)`.
- A method that calls an iterator method and returns the object it produces, like your `Test()`.
- A method that returns an instance of a type that implements the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface by hand.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.